# Is there an iframe-based 'embed' for the Hulu video player?

Tags: video, iframe, embed

I'm looking to 'embed' the Hulu player on my website, similar to how I would include a YouTube video, but can't seem to find the iframe code to do so anywhere online -- does anyone know what this code looks like or where I might find it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have an account to find it. Click the share button below the video player. Then click "Embed this Video" and it will generate a link for you like this `<iframe width="512" height="288" src="http://www.hulu.com/embed.html?eid=dg9je7apwgbj0zp8u1klra" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Hey @robmarston No problem!